automorphisms and mellin transforms
If a real analytic function $f$ is involutive i.e. $f(f(x))=x$ and its Mellin transform can be taken on a section of the real axis, and is analytic for $x>0$, in certain cases can this imply that $\tilde f$ inherits a functional equation as well? This functional equation should be symmetric about a vertical line in the complex plane.
I'm reminded by Poisson summation involving the Jacbobi theta function and its functional equation corresponding to a new functional equation under the Mellin transform. But I'm missing what conditions guarantee a new functional equation on $\tilde f$.
The point of this question is to try to get a handle on automorphisms of $f$ and whether an automorphism of $f$ can directly relate to an automorphism of a vertical strip in the complex plane. I am slightly doubtful of this but would like some more insights to be sure. References welcome.

For the function $$f(x)=x$$ the truncated Mellin transform $$F_k(s)=\int\limits_\frac{1}{k}^k x, x^{s-1} , dx=\frac{k^{s+1}-k^{-(s+1)}}{s+1},,\quad k>0\land k\ne 1$$ obeys the functional equation $$F_k(s)=F_k(-s-2).$$

thanks steven :)

Another example is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ where the truncated Mellin transform $$F_k(s)=\int\limits_\frac{1}{k}^k \frac{1}{x}, x^{s-1} , dx=\frac{k^{s-1}-k^{-(s-1)}}{s-1},\quad k>0\land k\ne 1$$ obeys the functional equation $$F_k(s)=F_k(2-s).$$

But $f(f(x))=x$ isn't required to invoke a functional equation since more generally for $$f(x)=x^j$$ the truncated Mellin transform $$F_{j,k}(s)=\int\limits_\frac{1}{k}^k x^j, x^{s-1} , dx=\frac{k^{s+j}-k^{-(s+j)}}{s+j},\quad k>0\land k\ne 1$$ obeys the functional equation $$F_{j,k}(s)=F_{j,k}(-2 j-s).$$ It may also be worth noting that $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} F_{j,k}(s)=\mathcal{M}_x\leftx^j\right=\int\limits_0^{\infty} x^j, x^{s-1} , dx=2 \pi \delta(i (s+j)).$$

@StevenClark in that spirit can a functional equation be found for $f(x)=\exp(\frac{1}{\log x})$ ?

@StevenClark the mellin transform of $f(x)$ is $F(s)=\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{s})}{\sqrt{s}}$ for modified bessel $K_1$

@StevenClark i meant, can a functional equation be found for $F(s)$..

You seem to have truncated the Mellin transform integral as
$$F_1(s)=\mathcal{M}_x\lefte^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}, (1-\theta(x-1))\right=\int\limits_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}, x^{s-1} , dx=\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{s})}{\sqrt{s}}\tag{1}.$$
One difference is that I believe $F_{j,k}(s)=\frac{k^{s+j}-k^{-(s+j)}}{s+j}$ has a removable singularity at $s=-j$ and is an entire function of $s$, whereas I believe $F_1(s)=\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{s})}{\sqrt{s}}$ is neither entire nor meromorphic as I believe the imaginary part of $F_1(s)$ has a branch cut along the negative real axis.

@StevenClark If you have an answer I'd be happy to review it. I just can't rule out some nontrivial functional equation that $F_1(s)$ might satisfy
